# loop through Wordpress Custom Post Type ACF field and get unique values

Tags: php, wordpress, foreach, advanced-custom-fields

I want to loop through Wordpress custom post type `career` field `country` all values and get each field value once to use them for filtering. It should likely be something similar to i.e:

```
$field_key = "field_64c18961a77a3";
$field = get_field_object($field_key);

if( $field )
{
    echo '<div class="acf-location-values">';
        foreach( $field['value'] as $k => $v )
        {
            echo '<a data-filter=.'.$k.' onclick="return false;">' . $v . '</a>';
        }
    echo '</div>';
}
```

The field setup in a plugin:

```
array(
        'key' => 'field_64c18961a77a3',
        'label' => 'Country',
        'name' => 'country',
        'aria-label' => '',
        'type' => 'text',
        'instructions' => '',
        'required' => 0,
        'conditional_logic' => 0,
        'wrapper' => array(
          'width' => '',
          'class' => '',
          'id' => '',
        ),
        'default_value' => '',
        'maxlength' => '',
        'placeholder' => '',
        'prepend' => '',
        'append' => '',
      ),
```

This doesn't seem to be giving me the expected result though (`Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()`)  - how to achieve this? Any advice appreciated.

EDIT:

var_dump for `$field`:

```
array(23) { ["ID"]=> int(0) ["key"]=> string(19) "field_64c18961a77a3" ["label"]=> string(7) "Country" ["name"]=> string(7) "country" ["aria-label"]=> string(0) "" ["prefix"]=> string(3) "acf" ["type"]=> string(4) "text" ["value"]=> string(2) "EE" ["menu_order"]=> int(5) ["instructions"]=> string(0) "" ["required"]=> int(0) ["id"]=> string(0) "" ["class"]=> string(0) "" ["conditional_logic"]=> int(0) ["parent"]=> string(19) "group_64c188737eb46" ["wrapper"]=> array(3) { ["width"]=> string(0) "" ["class"]=> string(0) "" ["id"]=> string(0) "" } ["default_value"]=> string(0) "" ["maxlength"]=> string(0) "" ["placeholder"]=> string(0) "" ["prepend"]=> string(0) "" ["append"]=> string(0) "" ["_name"]=> string(7) "country" ["_valid"]=> int(1) }
```

If I use `$field['value']` I still get a invalid argument. Should I put the foreach in a loop for the posts?

Comment: First, I'd just inspect `$field`. Second, `get_field_object` is usually used to get the global settings, not the per-instance one, that's `get_field`. The former wouldn't have a "country" property, but if it was a radio button list it would have a "choices" array.

Comment: Thanks, I've added the var_dump for $field. I'm a bit unsure how to apply this foreach - should I add it to the loop or does it get the field values from the field key and the foreach loop gets all values still. Although still getting an invalid argument

Comment: The reason I said to inspect it is to see if it is what you think it is. Do you see `country` in there at all? That's why I think you want `get_field` instead

Comment: That's true, i've added an edit. There seems to be rather: ["value"]=> string(2) "EE"

Comment: Your ACF field definition is a text field, so there isn't anything to `foreach` over. You should be able to just attempt to get the field and output it. Here's how we'd normally do it: https://3v4l.org/tSFjI

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in the right direction, I have a solution now @ChrisHaas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved the issue by getting the value from each field

```
$value = get_field('location');  
$all_attributes[] = $value;
```

And then creating a unique array based on the `$all_attributes` array:

```
<?php 
/* use array_unique to remove duplicates from the array */
$filter_attributes = array_unique ($all_attributes);
/* display the values on the same line, separated by spaces */
echo implode(" ", $filter_attributes ); ?>
```